# Rerender Child without rendering parent component React js

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React js. I need to rerender one of the child components from the parent component. One way is I can use setState for the matrix but the entire matrix which is parent component will be rerendered instead I want to rerender only one child component. This have added by code below.

**Child.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text : ""
        };
    }

    updateParent(text) {
        if(text) {
            this.setState({text : text});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>Child {this.state.text}</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Child;
```

**Parent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child'

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            table : [[<Child key={11}/>, <Child key={12}/>, <Child key={13}/>],
                     [<Child key={21}/>, <Child key={22}/>, <Child key={23}/>]],
            i : 0,
            j : 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID1 = setInterval(() => this.updateTable(), 1000);
    }

    updateTable() {
        //this.state.table[this.state.i][this.state.j].updateParent("");
        this.state.j++;
        if( this.state.j % 3 == 0) {
            this.state.i++;
            this.state.i %= 2;
        }
        //this.state.table[this.state.i][this.state.j].updateParent("*");
        // or tempTable[i][j] = <Child key={ij} text={"*"}/>; this.setState({table: tempTable});
        this.state.j++;
    }

    createTable() {
        let table = []
        for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            table.push( <div key={i} style={{display:"flex"}}>{this.state.table[0]}</div> )
        }
        return table;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>{this.createTable()}</div>
        );
    }
}
export default Parent;
```

Comment: why are you calling 6 time child component

Comment: You should iterate over table and render <Child /> for each iteration.
Currently you have hardcoded them.

Comment: @arslan considers I am creating a chessboard child refers to each square. So I need 8 x 8 squares arranged in a matrix and the parameters will be coins.

Comment: @UtsavPatel could you share some code please.

Comment: it doesnt matter 9x8 or whatever just pass the props parent to child

Comment: @arslan I am new to react. I just don't get your idea. share some code.

Comment: you can update child component without rerendering parent component by using ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't store Child component instances in state, instead render them dynamically
- You can implement Child as a PureComponent so that if no props or state change for it, it doesn't re-render
- Do not mutate state directly like you do `this.state.j++` and so on. Use setState

Parent.js

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      table: this.createTableData(3),
      i: 0,
      j: 0
    };
  }

  createTableData(size) {
    const arr = new Array(size);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      arr[i] = new Array(size).fill("");
    }
    return arr;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID1 = setInterval(() => this.updateTable(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID1);
  }
  updateTable() {
    let { i, j, table } = this.state;
    j++;
    if (j % 3 == 0) {
      i++;
      i %= 2;
    }
    const newTable = table.map((tr, row) => {
      return tr.map((td, col) => {
        if (row == i && col == j) {
          return "*";
        } else {
          return "";
        }
      });
    });
    j++;
    this.setState({
      table: newTable,
      i,
      j
    });
  }

  createTable() {
    return this.state.table.map((row, i) => {
      return (
        <div className="row">
          {row.map((col, j) => {
            return <Child key={`${i + 1}${j + 1}`} text={col} />;
          })}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createTable()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Child.js

```
class Child extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("child rerender", this.props.text);
    return <div>Child {this.props.text} &nbsp;</div>;
  }
}
```

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-banach-rulsw?file=/src/App.js)

**NOTE:** The demo only contains the display and performance optimization logic along with the architecture, The logic to update the indexes i, j needs to be done by you in updateTable method.

If you look at the demo, only the cell you whose value changed from "" to "*" and vice versa will re-render, the rest will not

Answer (score 0):

**you can rerender child component without rendering parent component**

by using **ref** to call child function from parent and update child component

**Parent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Table from "./Table";
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.table = [
      [<Child key={11} />, <Child key={12} />, <Child key={13} />],
      [<Child key={21} />, <Child key={22} />, <Child key={23} />],
    ];
    this.i = 0;
    this.j = 0;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID1 = setInterval(() => this.updateTable(), 1000);
  }

  updateTable() {
    this.j++;
    if (this.j % 3 == 0) {
      this.i++;
      this.i %= 2;
    }
    this.j++;
    this.table[0].push(
      <Child key={21} />,
      <Child key={22} />,
      <Child key={23} />
    );
    this.refs.table.updateTable(this.table[0]);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("component rerender");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Parent Component</h1>
        <Table ref="table" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Parent;
```

**Child.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text : ""
        };
    }

    updateParent(text) {
        if(text) {
            this.setState({text : text});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>Child {this.state.text}</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Child;
```

**Table.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class table extends Component {
  state = {
    table: [],
  };

  updateTable = (table) => {
    this.setState({ table });
  };
  render() {
    const { table } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {table.map((tableItem, i) => {
          return <div key={i} style={{ display: "flex" }}>{tableItem}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default table;
```

**componentDidUpdate** will give log if rerendering is happen

**Note:** I did not use state in parent component. if you want to use parent component state then you have to stop rerendering by using **shouldComponentUpdate** lifecycle